# Asymptote criterion

Tags: limits, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Let $f:(a, \infty)\to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function such that exists $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=l<\infty$ and exists (in the sense it can also be infinity) $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$. Under these hypothesis we can conclude that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$.

I found a proof which says the following:
by Lagrange theorem for every $x$ there exists a number $\eta_x$ in between $x$ and $x+1$ such that $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(\eta_x)$.  So we conclude that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(\eta_x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))=l-l=0$.

Is this really a proof?  I suspect it is wrong as a proof.  Should we ensure that there exists such a *continuous* function $x\mapsto\eta_x$?
In fact, for example, $\eta$ could assume only integer values, because between $x$ and $x+1$ there always is an integer $n$.  So, in this case we could only conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f'(n)=0$ (where $n$ is an integer), and not that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$ (where $x$ is any real number).

How can we "save" this proof?

Comment: The proof is fine. $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f'(x)=M$ is assumed to exist. If $(a_n)$ has limit infinity, then it follows that $f'(a_n)\rightarrow M$.

Comment: @David Mitra. Yes, you are right.  I was stupid

Comment: Don't say that. You'd have realized it was ok soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by David Mitra, you don't need continuity of the map $x\mapsto \eta_x$, but only the fact that $\eta_n\to +\infty$ as $n$ goes to infinity (because $\eta_n\geqslant n$). Since it is *assumed* that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)$ exists, and is equal to (say) $L$, we have $\lim_{n\to +\infty}f'(\eta_n)=L$, and we conclude that $L=0$ by your computations.