# Vertical asymptote criterion

Tags: real-analysis

As quest [Asymptote criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372972/asymptote-criterion), i ask if i true that:

Let $f:(x_0,b)→\mathbb{R}$ (where $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$)
be a differentiable function such that:

1. exists $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)=+\infty$ (or $-\infty$).
2. exists  $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}f′(x)$.

Then   $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}f′(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)$.

I ask help for proof or a counterexample, please.

Note that:

- hypotesis 1 not implies 2; for exemples the function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}+sin\biggl(\dfrac{1}{x}\biggr)$ has $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f′(x)$ don't exists.
- hypotesis 2 (with infinite values) not implies 1; for exemple the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ has in $x_0=0$ a vertical tangent and no has a vertical asymptote
  .